# Have a command that creates new commands discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to have a command that can create new commands on its own for example:

`!newcommand newcommandname commandtext`

would let you now call !newcommandname with commandtext being the response

How would this be approached? or if its possible at all, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [add_command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=add_command#discord.ext.commands.Bot.add_command), but I prefer to write the command manually instead using `@client.command`

**NOTE:** The command won't saved. it will exist until your bot turned off only, after that it will gone